# Invalid object name [UserInfo_Table_Azure]

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, azure

I'm using mobile service of Windows Azure to store data which retrieved from my windows phone application. In my project, I need to generate a pdf when a user needs on website. So I'm using PHP to generate a PDFs which I need to get data from a table in mobile service.

However, when I try to get data, I always receive this error from Windows Azure (SQL server?).

> MySql Connected [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'UserInfo_Table_Azure'. Failed to query test table: SELECT Username FROM [UserInfo_Table_Azure]

This is my code

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$dbName, "UID"=>$userName, "PWD"=>$userPassword, "MultipleActiveResultSets"=>true);

    sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors', 0);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if($conn === false)
    {
    FatalError("Failed to connect...");
    } else {
    echo "Sql Connected \n";
    }

    $tsql = "SELECT Username FROM [$table]";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
    if ($stmt === false)
    {
    FatalError("Failed to query test table: ".$tsql);
    }
    else
    {
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
    {
    echo "Col1: ".$row[0]."\n";
    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
    }
```

It always shows "Sql connected" but can't get data from the table.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
if($conn == "false") {
        FatalError("Failed to connect...");
    } else {
        echo "Sql Connected \n";
    }
```

it will be 100% guarantee about connection success

Comment: I check it every time I run my code. It always show "Sql Connected". Because it was connected, that why I'm so confused right now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I can find the solution. The problem is the schema of mobile service is not a default schema. The schema of tables in mobile service is set according to your mobile service name. For example, if my mobile service name is "School", what I have to do to get data in this mobile service is to use [School].[a table name] instead of just [a table name].